# Hide file names of files completely in the url

Tags: url

I want to access multiply downloadable pdf files in the same folder while hiding the ".pdf" extension in the url. It doesn't seem to work with a .htaccess file. 
For example: How can I download the files at "example.com/subfolder/one.html" "example.com/subfolder/two.html" with the urls "example.com/subfolder/one" and "example.com/subfolder/two"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to my problem:

I will explain it with this example:
The file "one.pdf" is located in "example.com/subfolder/" (The full url to normally download the pdf is "example.com/subfolder/one.pdf)

To change that download url to "example.com/subfolder/one you have to create a file "one.html" in the same folder with the following content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=https://www.example.com/subfolder/one.pdf">
</head>
<!--The following lines aren't necessary for the download and are only there if the automatic download doesn't work-->
<body>
  <p>If the download doesn't start automatically: <a href="https://www.example.com/subfolder/one.pdf" >please click here</a>.</p>
  <p>Back to the homepage: <a href="https://www.example.com" >www.example.com</a></p>
</body>

</html>
```

You have to create a html file for every pdf file.
The pdfs don't have to be in the same folder as the html files.
The names of the html and pdf files don't have to match. But the name of the url folder "example.com/subfolder/**one**" has to match with the name of the html file (**one**.html)
You have to do this for every file

Answer (score 0):

Request example.com/example.pdf load file from example.com/subfolder/example.pdf

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^example\.pdf$ /subfolder/example.pdf [L]
```

or rewrite all requests to pdf files from root to subfolder - example.com/filename.pdf to example.com/subfolder/filename.pdf

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*).pdf$ /subfolder/$1.pdf [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me.
I edited my post to clariy my question. My aim is it to hide the names of the pdfs completely and only show the folder they are located, in in the url.